# hypertext in gridview

Tags: c#, asp.net, gridview

i have a gridview with rows of a particular column(name of employees) set as hyperlink. when i click on the hyperlinks all should direct to the same page.however i want the name of the employee to be sent to the directed page for further processing.how do i achieve this? 
i have already created the names of the employees as hyperlink , but m unable to send the name of the employee.

```
protected void GridView1_RowDataBound(object sender, GridViewRowEventArgs e){    
            if (e.Row.RowType == DataControlRowType.DataRow)
            {
                HyperLink link = new HyperLink();
                link.Text = e.Row.Cells[0].Text;
                link.NavigateUrl = "Goal_AssignmentPage.aspx";
                e.Row.Cells[0].Controls.Add(link);
            }
        }
```

i should be able to access the string within e.Row.Cells[0].Text in the Goal_AssignmentPage.aspx

Comment: you can use the request collectrtion at called page i.e Goal_Assignmentpage.aspx to get the value of the employee name

Comment: answer is updated now check it

Answer (score 2, accepted):

just append the link.text witht he navigatio url as i did

```
protected void GridView1_RowDataBound(object sender, GridViewRowEventArgs e){

        if (e.Row.RowType == DataControlRowType.DataRow)
        {
            HyperLink link = new HyperLink();
            link.Text = e.Row.Cells[0].Text;
            link.NavigateUrl = "Goal_AssignmentPage.aspx?employeename=" + link.Text; // change in your code
            e.Row.Cells[0].Controls.Add(link);
        }
    }
```

In **Goal_AssignmentPage.aspx** ->> page load method

write `Request.QueryString["employeename"]` to get value

Comment: but then how do i receive the string in the goalAssignment page.??

Comment: It should be like **?Name=" + link.Text** and on the other page **Request.QueryString["Name"]** should do the trick

Comment: sorry, but i didnt get what u said. can u please be clearer.?